# Is there is a way to create video recorder in react.js app whith options to add photo and text in it?

Tags: reactjs, image, video, text, recorder

Am trying to create react.js app .. contains video recorder that have the ability to add pictures and text to this video at specific time .

i found [video.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-record#examples) but this is not what am lonking for .
any help ??

Comment: Did you find any solution??

Comment: no, i customize it .. if you need any help with it .tell me!